# Advance PDF Viewer : Failed assertion: line 4263 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, pdfview

I am getting the error when I try to load the pdf from URL.
It shows the number of pages of pdf but then error appears on the screen.

[image: Screenshot of error]

[Using plugin - https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer)

Logcat:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library 

=======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///D:/GST%20with%20GT/gst_with_gt/lib/screens/pdfview.dart:70:19
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _PDFPageState._repaint (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/page.dart:54:45)
#1      _PDFPageState.didChangeDependencies (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/page.dart:42:5)
#2      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4725:11)
#3      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4541:5)
#4      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3603:14)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building SliverFillViewport:
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 258 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///D:/GST%20with%20GT/gst_with_gt/lib/screens/pdfview.dart:70:19
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._debugVerifyChildOrder (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:258:16)
#3      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.debugChildIntegrityEnabled=.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:233:14)
#4      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.debugChildIntegrityEnabled= (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:235:6)
#5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1208:20)
#6      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1124:7)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#411e6](state: RawGestureDetectorState#4acaf(gestures: <none>, behavior: opaque)):
A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.

RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderViewport that expected a RenderSliver child was created by: Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#e5bfe] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#411e6] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#3ad9e] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
The RenderErrorBox that did not match the expected child type was created by: ErrorWidget-[#87a59] ← SliverFillViewport ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#e5bfe] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#411e6] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#3ad9e] ← RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///D:/GST%20with%20GT/gst_with_gt/lib/screens/pdfview.dart:70:19
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3134:9)
#1      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3161:6)
#2      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6127:25)
#3      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5737:35)
#4      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5433:5)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building _ScrollableScope:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4263 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///D:/GST%20with%20GT/gst_with_gt/lib/screens/pdfview.dart:70:19
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      Element.rebuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4263:14)
#3      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4266:6)
#4      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4771:5)
#5      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3345:15)
#6      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6057:14)
...
```

Here, my code :

```
class PdfViewers extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  PdfViewersState createState() => PdfViewersState();
}

    class PdfViewersState extends State<PdfViewers> {
      bool _isLoadings = true;
      PDFDocument docs;
    
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        Timer(
          Duration(seconds: 1),
          () => loadUrl(),
        );
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
            appBar: AppBar(
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
              actions: [
                
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.share_rounded,
                      color: Color(0xff4f2e7f),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {}),
              ],
              title: Text(
                'PDF Article',
                softWrap: true,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff4f2e7f)),
              ),
              leading: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, true);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined, color: Color(0xff4f2e7f))),
            ),
            body: Center(
                child: _isLoadings
                    ? Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                    : PDFViewer(document: docs)));
      }
    
      Future<void> loadUrl() async {
        setState(() {
          _isLoadings = true;
        });
    
        docs= await PDFDocument.fromURL(
            'https://gstwithgt.fivestake.com/uploads/topics/16254191793470.pdf');
    
        setState(() {
          _isLoadings = false;
        });
      }
    


}
```

I tried and searched many tutorials and example but none of them are working for me. so I posted question here.

The main thing is when I paste this same code in another project then it is working fine. I don't know where the problem is.. I'm trying to solve this error since last two days..

Comment: how u solve this?

Comment: Because of firebase messaging error occured when I removed this line my pdf viewer is working fine.

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);  

this line in homescreen and error solved..

I find error from very first line in log cat.
The following _CastError was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:

so I removed firebase messaging.OnBackground() line and its worked.

Comment: @SachinSolanki I have had exactly the same issue and spent a while looking for the problem. Eventually, I removed all my firebase stuff (as that was the most recent major change I made) and started adding things back in bit by bit. I eventually found that it also was FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage. (I wish I had seen this thread before, would have saved so much time). My problem only arises in release, not debug. However, is there any way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.
You can find here the full discussion: https://github.com/lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer/issues/62

It seems that on the first try to open the file it returns null from here:

```
var data = await _channel .invokeMethod('getPage', {'filePath': _filePath, 'pageNumber': page});
```

(From **document.dart** file)

The interesting thing is that after I reopen my app **everything works fine**.

**This patch solved this exception for me:**

I have noticed that before I reopen the application (which solves the issue) and I try to open the PDF, I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.app.Activity.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

But when I reopen the app and everything works, this exception disappears. So, I have looked for this exception in this repository issues and encountered this fix:

https://github.com/lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer/issues/45

After implementing **RasyidMF** solution, the PDF opens correctly.